# Two sample test for both equal variance and mean

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, sample

For two normally distributed samples, is there a way to test for $H_0: \mu_1=\mu_2$ and also $\sigma_1^2=\sigma_2^2$. I have computed the likelihood ratio, but cannot recognize the underlying distribution.

Comment: FYI, you should test for the equality of variances prior to testing $\mu_1=\mu_2$ so you know which two-sample test is required.

Comment: @Ken, you could do that, but I think he's asking how to jointly test them both with a single hypothesis test.

Comment: Yes, it has to be a single test.

Comment: @Ken, whoever told you that is badly out of date (and wrong, which is worse). See, for example Zimmerman 2004 "A note on preliminary tests of equality of variances" or Rasch 2009 "The two-sample t test: pre-testing its assumptions does not pay off". If you don't have a reason to suppose the variances are equal, use the unequal variance version of the t-test. 

SamuelJ, you could compute the LR statistic and use it in a permutation test, that would work, if perhaps inelegantly.

Answer (score 6):

You could do a likelihood ratio test. Calculate the MLE for each data set separately:

$$ L_1 \equiv \max_{\mu_{1}, \sigma_{1}} L_{1}(\mu_{1}, \sigma_{1}) $$

$$ L_2 \equiv \max_{\mu_{2}, \sigma_{2}} L_{2}(\mu_{2}, \sigma_{2}) $$

where $L_1$ is the log-likelihood function for the first data set and $L_2$ is the log-likelihood function for the second. Then, if the two data sets are independent, the maximized log-likelihood for the full data set (i.e. the two data sets together) is $L_1 + L_2$. This is the maximized log-likelihood when the two data sets are not restricted to having the same mean and variance.

Now, to get the MLE under the constraint that the two populations do have the same mean, you calculate

$$ L_{0} = \max_{\mu, \sigma} L(\mu, \sigma) $$

where $L$ is the log-likelihood function for the full data set. Then, under the null hypothesis you specified in your question,

$$ \lambda = 2 \bigg( (L_1 + L_2) - L_0 \bigg) $$

has an approximate (i.e. asymptotic) $\chi^2$ distribution on 2 degrees of freedom, assuming that the null hypothesis being tested doesn't include $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2 = 0$, which clearly can't be the case if you observe non-zero variance in your data. You can use that null distribution for significance testing.

**Note:** The joint MLE for the normally distributed data is the sample mean:

$$ \hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i $$

and the sample variance:

$$ \hat{\sigma}^{2} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-\hat{\mu})^2$$

Comment: I need to find the exact distribution, not an approximate distribution. It will depend on the actual likelihoods and $S_{XX}, S_{YY}, \bar{x}-\bar{y}$.

Comment: So, you're asking for the exact distribution of the (log) likelihood ratio in finite samples? This might be very complicated. I'd suggest a permutation test or looking at literature for special cases where the exact distribution of the likelihood ratio is derived and try to mimic the proof (e.g. http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/2336564).

Comment: If you have a decent sample size, this approximation will be good. If you have a small sample size, I'd suggest a permutation test based on permuting the group labels and repeating to get the permutation distribution of the log likelihood ratio, which should be a good approximation of the actual sampling distribution of the likelihood ratio.

Comment: I got the following likelihood

$$ \frac{\left[ S_{XX}+S_{YY}+ \frac{mn}{m+n}(\bar{x}-\bar{y})^2 \right]^{(m+n)/2}}{(S_{XX}/m)^{m/2}(S_{YY}/n)^{n/2}}$$

Comment: We can always pin down the exact distribution for either equal means test or equal variance test, so intuitively we should be able to here. For example, if numerator and denumerator are independent, we are done, since it is a ratio of chi-squared distributions.

Comment: @Macro: (1) Until $\lambda$ is introduced, $L_0$, $L_1$, and $L_2$ are explicitly named as "likelihoods."  After that, though, you appear to be using them as log likelihoods.  (2) What do you mean by "$\sigma_1 =\sigma_2 = 0$ ... has probability 0"?  Likelihoods are not probability distributions for parameters.

Comment: thanks @whuber. I fixed these inconsistencies. All meant regarding the $\sigma_{1}=\sigma_{2}=0$ thing was that the likelihood ratio test is not valid when the null hypothesis is on the boundary of the parameter space, which it isn't in this case, unless both variances are 0, which they can't be if you observe variation in the data sets.

Comment: @SamuelJ, it may be possible to get an exact distribution, but I disagree with the 'therefore' of your comment "..., so intuitively we should be able to here" - just because both null distributions corresponding the single parameters can be derived doesn't imply it is tractable to derive the null distribution for the combined hypothesis. In this case, since the asymptotic distribution is so commonly used, I'm skeptical about whether the exact distribution can be derived tractably. I'll have to think about your most recent question more carefully...

Comment: Thanks, @Macro.  I'm still confused by something.  Stating that the "null hypothesis is on the boundary" restricts the *parameters* whereas "observ[ing] variation in the data sets" says something about the *data*.  I don't see a direct connection here.  Are you perhaps referring to the problem that the *MLE* of the parameters will be on the boundary when there is no variation in the data?

Comment: well, if both variances were zero, then one possibility where the null could be true is $\sigma_{1} = \sigma_{2} = 0$, which violates an assumption of the LRT. We can preclude this possibility, since we know for a fact that won't be the case (since we observed variation in both groups). Is there something wrong with this reasoning?